# How to move python project from Netbeans in windows to Ubuntu

Tags: python, netbeans, ubuntu, wxpython

Ok, so I spent about 20 hours trying to install pypoker and wxPython in windows and finally gave up. So I installed Ubuntu and got that working. Now, how do i get my Netbeans project to Ubuntu? i straight up copied my src folder in netbeans and put it in ubuntu, but when i typed python "name", all i get is segmentation fault as the output. Is there a simple way to do this, or will i have to go line by line and put it into ubuntu?

Comment: Does Netbeans by itself work OK from within Ubuntu?

Comment: There is a netbeans for ubuntu? gonna look that up, was trying to use DrPython

Answer (score 1):

Start by installing [netbeans](http://packages.ubuntu.com/netbeans) [Install netbeans http://bit.ly/software-large](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/netbeans)  and go from there.

Not sure of the exact dependencies, but try installing python-wxgtk2.8 (or 2.6) and wx-common (and possibly python-wxtools) if you haven't.

Comment: Okay I installed Netbeans, and opened my project. It uses wxPython. When i go to run, it just does nothing, it "runs" for about 2 seconds then stops. no window popup or anything

Comment: @ULCajun  I've updated the answer slightly, but you might try doing a more simple test case to make sure everything is found and working.  Once that is OK, go on trying to get your project up.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a small case, make a window, load a background image. That worked, So i tried to copy my code into that file, and same thing happened, no popup, no error message, no nothing. So i guess i will be tracing through copying a little bit at a time to find out what is killing it. thanks for the help